# Intellij idea / phpstorm database UML diagram foreign key bug?

Tags: intellij-idea, uml, diagram, phpstorm

I can't see connections (foreign keys) in database diagram generated with intellij (using phpstorm 6.0.3). [Here](http://tv.jetbrains.net/videocontent/%5Btitle-raw%5D-46) is video showing some intelij features and that guys has his foreing keys visible and linked. And [here](http://www.modelaznehtu-praha.cz/SMETI/diagram.png) is my screenshot. Any idea why? Is it a bug?

Here is short table generating code example copied from my db:

```
Create table Book (
  id Integer Not Null Auto_increment,
  Ad_id Integer Not Null,
  title VarChar(150) Not Null,
  isbn VarChar(80) Null,      
  Constraint PK_Book Primary Key (id)
);
Create table Ad (
  id Integer Not Null Auto_increment,      
  displayed Integer Not Null,
  price Integer Not Null,
  inserted Integer Not Null,
  Constraint PK_Ad Primary Key (id)
);    
Alter table Book add (
  Constraint FK_Book_1 Foreign Key (Ad_id) References Ad(id) On Update Cascade On Delete Cascade
);
```

Comment: Purely based on screenshots: do you actually have foreign keys in your DB/tables? The foreign keys should have **blue** key icon (when you browsing DB structure .. or on diagram (when field is not primary key already). Too bad that I do not have any DB on hand that has foreign keys in use (so that I can verify it from my side)...

Comment: Yea I am sure. When I run MySQL statements on this db structure it respects foreign keys as it should. I will add some example sql generating the tables.

Comment: Works for me (MySQL db): http://s17.postimg.org/qxfymho8v/screen01.png -- that's how IDE built it for me. PhpStorm build 130.1293 here.

Comment: Hmm, interesting My build is 129.814 and IDE says its up to date when I try to update it. What theme do you use? Default one? I tryed few themes (including default one) with same result. Maybe I will just have to wait for another IDE update.

Comment: I do not see how IDE theme should affect this. But yes -- default editor colors and GUI theme = "Windows". 129.xxx builds are v6 (latest stable). 130.xxx are EAP build (public dev builds of next version): http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program

Comment: Yea I also dont think it should but you never know. The arrow could have same color as background or any other stupid mistake. Alright, thanks for the help, I will jsut wait for another update and I am gonna update the post here if it was the problem.

Comment: If you think that UI theme may cause arrows to disappear ... then 1) switch theme 2) Create brand new project 3) Connect to sample DB (the one that you gave me is fine) 4) see how it will work (post a screenshot) 5) double check the context menu on such diagram (screenshot) -- maybe some options are turned off

Comment: Huh funny thing happened, I was still in database modeling process, so I edded, even changed few tables and foreign keys are now visible like a magic. Maybe the problem was in the design altho the database generating script was working fine before with no errors and warnings. Or it could be some strange problem with synchronisation becouse I noticed before that tables are not updating every time I make some changes and I had to restart IDE few times and now sync is working just fine. Thanks for the effort lazyOne ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was definately bug. The diagram sometimes shows foreign keys and sometimes not with very same sql script generating the database. I have a feeling it is coused by bad synchronisation but I have nothing to prove it.

Comment: Later I found out that my hosting uses mysql engine witch doesnt support foreign keys. I had to switch to inno db engine witch does. Since then diagram works fine.